# How to add fadeIn effect for fixed div on scroll position

Tags: jquery

I need a fadeIn effect when appear the fixed div. I gave scroll time to fixed the top div.Its working but I need a smoother result like fadeIn. Below added my script and jsfiddle link

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var sticky = $('.sticky'),
scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll >= 150) sticky.addClass('fixed');
else sticky.removeClass('fixed'); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ansarmon/0mnvmf3d/4/

Comment: Do you need to wait until the page is scrolled before adding the fixed class? Having it on "sticky" from the get go should negate the need to animate it being added back on.

Comment: I need a smooth transition for the appear and disappearance of that Div.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the css animation keyframes like this, see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hk6s5tkz/)

```
.fixed{
    animation: appear linear 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes appear{
    0% {
    opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
    opacity:1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, Nice But It happens only when appear, when disappearing it goes suddenly.

Comment: Well the problem with this method is, if you make it disappear with a fade out, the element will be hidden, even at the top, look this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgsb1ks3/).
Maybe should you duplicate your element ? The real at the top of your docuement, and a fixed copy wich appear and disappear when you scroll

Comment: Yes I tried with fadeIn and fadeOut but got the same result. let me check with duplicate. I saw that fiddle, it fade out on loading the page itself, but when scroll to top it goes suddenly.